# Graph: PropertyValue changes and Dynamic

Tags: graphs-and-networks, dynamic

I almost never work with `Graph` in *Mathematica* but lately I [helped someone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18244625#18244625) with it. For this, I tried to make an animation using `Dynamic` and an issue came up that I don't clearly understand: It seems when changing the state of a given graph using `PropertyValue`, this is not reflected in a `Dynamic` setting. Simple example:

```
g = RandomGraph[{5, 5}];
Dynamic[g]
```

If you now change for instance the styling of a vertex, the dynamic `g` is not updated

```
PropertyValue[{g, 1}, VertexStyle] = Blue
```

> Question: Can someone explain what happens and why this does not work?

---

#### Further findings

When I tried to investigate in this behavior, something else came up. First, I used `Refresh` to force a reload of `g` which *seemed* to work

```
Dynamic[Refresh[g, UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

but when I changed the state of `g` in a loop (or several times), then something mysterious happens

```
Do[
 Pause[1.3]; 
 PropertyValue[{g, RandomInteger[5]}, VertexStyle] = RandomColor[],
 {20}
]
```

Eventually, the graph `g` ends up being displayed as

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

If you look at the `InputForm` of `g` and copy this into a new cell, you get a nice graph again, but it doesn't seem possible to change the representation of `g` again

Comment: Not by far being en expert in Graph-related stuff, one thing that came to mind is that `Graph` is a departure from usual Mathematica strategy for objects in that it is a mutable object. And mutation via property changes is a different mechanism than via variable changes etc. I'd just think that the integration of Graphs with `Dynamic` (concerning their internal state) is probably not as tight as it is between `Dynamic` and the core language. At least, this behavior doesn't come as a surprise for me, rather I'd be surprised if it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Exactly what I guessed and I'm stunned that WRI introduces mutability to such highly efficient objects as graphs, without incorporating this functionality into their flagship of advertisement: `Dynamic`. Btw, I saw that `PropertyValue` is quite old as it was introduced in V8. Surprising that no-one asked this question until now.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The most unfortunate thing is that it is hard, even for advanced users, to look behind this curtain. One day everything works and you think you know how things are and the next day you cannot replace expressions inside `Image` or `Graph` and you have to find out the hard way that it is atomic now. And to say "Graph objects are atomic raw objects" in the very last paragraph of the help page doesn't help either, because it is not obvious what consequences this has.

Comment: I totally agree. To my mind, this shows the limitations of the current model of the language, where the core is not cleanly separated from the rest, and where the rest can't be implemented using the core, but requires adding more C code for every new piece where performance is important. This certainly adds complexity to the language, and is perhaps on of its most fundamental problems, that eventually needs to be solved, for the language to successfully evolve.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Graphs are immutable objects. Property only provides an efficient way to emulate mutation.

Comment: @halirutan I can reproduce this issue in Mathematica 10.  Dynamic[g] works correctly in Mathematica 9.

Comment: @CharlesP. Charles, thanks for the correction. I wasn't entirely sure. I will delete come of my incorrect comments soon. And I was sure that whatever the design was, you had good reasons for that. But does that mean that change of property value, in a `Graph`, constructs a new `Graph`,  like e.g. when we add a key-value pair to an `Association`? B.t.w., great to see you here! I should've made some incorrect and provocative remark on `Graph`-s earlier, to drag you to this site :)

Comment: @CharlesP. Thanks for the comment. Would it be possible that you write up an answer and provide some details about why it goes wrong and how the *faked mutability* is achieved for `Graph` objects? I'm especially interested in whether a deep copy of a graph is made or whether (which is surely the case) the graph-data itself is kept and only the properties are created new. I guess this would be a very interesting insight for many of the advanced users here.

Comment: @halirutan do you think it will be very inefficient? `g = SetProperty[{g, RandomInteger[50]}, VertexStyle -> Blue]` assignment itself because when the graph is huge updating dynamic will be slow whether "mutation" was done efficiently or not, right?

Comment: @Kuba It depends on whether *Mathematica* is clever enough to see that the assignment doesn't need a copy. Unfortunately, I'm not able to test this. In none of my Mathematica versions is SetProperty working correctly in a e.g. `Do` loop with many iterations. I tried to time stuff, but it just does not work. Sorry.